# Why are most ordered pairs (ind, dep) but we use (r, theta) for polar functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Most of high school mathematics works on the assumption that the abscissa is the independent variable and the ordinate is the dependent variable and the ordered pair is written as such (abs, ord) = (ind, dep). Yet when we consider polar coordinates, r is written as a function of theta (r = f(theta)). So theta is independent and the radius dependent. Yet when we write the ordered pair we reverse the order - (r, theta) = (dep, ind).
Why is this?
When considering ordered pairs and their definition, what is the best way to prepare students for college-level (and higher) mathematics?

Comment: The order does not *really* matter. It is probably better for *teaching* maths to set up some standard which co-ordinate is written first, but there isn't a particular *mathematical* reason to write either one first (or second).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question presumes an order of dependence between the coordinates that is not always the case.  Yes, it is a *convention* that we often plot functions of the form $y = f(x)$ in the order that you describe, where the horizontal axis is the independent variable and the vertical the dependent.  And similarly, in polar coordinates, it is a convention to conceptualize the radius $r$ as a function of angle $\theta$.  But this is not always true; for example, we could plot a *relation*  $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ that describes a circle in the coordinate plane.  And in polar coordinates, that same circle would have the equation $$r = 1.$$

Moreover, in a polar coordinate system, we could write more complex curves in which neither $r$ nor $\theta$ can be expressed as an explicit function of the other.  Mathematics is rife with examples like this in which we write things according to convention, rather than some underlying consistent rule.